# Playing youtube video on Android app using Youtube API

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using `Youtube API` to make an app which displays list of video from youtube. Users can watch video directly on my app. My question is: "Playing youtube video directly on Android app is legal? If it is, Is there any limit number of views?"

If you have any experience with youtube API, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Playing YouTube videos from your Android application is perfectly legal provided you agree to the YouTube API [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) and by extension the [Google Play Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/about/play-terms.html).

When developing your application, you will most likely use a Developer Key specified in your [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

If you release your app via Google Play, you will of course want those who use your app to authenticate with their own YouTube credentials via [OAuth 2.0 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

Comment: Could you please give me more details "why do we need users to  authenticate with their own YouTube credentials?" Because currently, I just added Developer Key and I still can watch the videos. Thanks!

Comment: YouTube (Google) will most likely shut down your released app if they see too many requests coming in using your developer key. You will be fine for a small user base, but as more people use your app, more API requests are called using your Dev key. There is a limit on the number of API requests you can make using the same authentication scheme - this is true for maps, translation, Blogger, etc.. Also, utilizing OAuth 2.0 allows you to *not* have to store any user credentials in your app. As a user, I would also want my YouTube history and preferences preserved.

Comment: Could you help me by providing sample code for this process?

Comment: My app just simply displays list of video and play this selected video using supported Youtube player like YouTubeStandalonePlayer. So what is the maximum of API request my app can use?

Comment: I just got my app removed right after publishing. Google said that I violated section 4.4 of Developer Distribution Agreement. Don't know why :(